# Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. CSOM SP13

Tags: powershell, client-object-model

I'm trying to add a page to my search centre in sharepoint 2013. Trying out cSOM too.
Here is my code, I am getting a bug Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

```
function New-SearchResultsPage() 
{

    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$siteurl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$PageTitle,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$PageLayoutName
    )

    try
    {

    # Authenticate with site.
    $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteurl) 
    $ctx.Credentials = $credentials

    # Get the SearchResults page layout item needed for setting the
    # page layout list item property for new publishing pages.
    $rootWeb = $ctx.Site.RootWeb
    $mpList = $rootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle('Master Page Gallery')
    $camlQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $camlQuery.ViewXml = '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" /><Value Type="Text">'+$PageLayoutName+'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'
    $items = $mpList.GetItems($camlQuery)
    $ctx.Load($items)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $pageLayoutItem = $items[0]
    $ctx.Load($pageLayoutItem)

    # Get publishing web object
    #
    $web = $ctx.Web
    $pubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($ctx, $web)
    $ctx.Load($pubWeb)

    # Setup for blog post creation using CSV file as input.
    #
    $pagesList = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('Pages')

    Write-Host ("Creating custom result page")
    Write-Output("Creating custom result page")
    # Create page information instance, update properties, 
    # add it, check it in, publish it, and approve it.
    #   
    $pubPageInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.PublishingPageInformation
    $pubPageInfo.Name = $PageTitle.Replace(" ", "-") + ".aspx"
    $pubPageInfo.PageLayoutListItem = $pageLayoutItem 
    $pubPage = $pubWeb.AddPublishingpage($pubPageInfo)

    $pubPage.ListItem.File.CheckIn("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
    $pubPage.ListItem.File.Publish("")
    #$pubPage.ListItem.File.Approve("")

    $ctx.Load($pubPage) 
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host ("Custom result page created !") -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Write-Output("Custom result page created !")
    Write-Host ("Preparing to update page title")
    Write-Output("Preparing to update page title")
    # Page added.  Now retrieve list item, check it out, 
    # update title and page content, and check back in.
    #
    $listItem = $pubPage.get_listItem()
    $ctx.Load($listItem)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    $file = $listItem.File
    $file.CheckOut()
    $ctx.Load($file)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    $listItem.Set_Item("Title", $PageTitle)
    $listItem.Update()
    $listItem.File.CheckIn("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
    $listItem.File.Publish("")
    #clear$listItem.File.Approve("")
    $ctx.Load($listItem)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    Write-Host ("Search result page created successfully !") -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Write-Output ("Search result page created successfully !")

    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host ("Error while creating search result page. Error -->> " + $_.Exception.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Output("Error while creating search result page. Error -->> " + $_.Exception.Message)
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the proper version of SharePoint 2013 Client Components SDK ([SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)) is installed on the client machine.

The following script allows to create a Publishing Page using CSOM:

```
param (
    [string]$Url,
    [string]$UserName,
    [string]$Password,
    [string]$PageName,
    [string]$PageLayoutName
 )

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing")




Function Add-PublishingPage([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, [string]$PageName,[string]$PageLayoutName,[hashtable]$Properties)
{
    $pubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($Context, $Context.Web)
    $pageInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.PublishingPageInformation
    $pageInfo.Name = $PageName
    $pageInfo.PageLayoutListItem = Get-PageLayout -Context $Context -Name $PageLayoutName
    $publishingPage = $pubWeb.AddPublishingPage($pageInfo)
    $pageItem = $publishingPage.ListItem
    foreach ($p in $Properties)
    {
       $pageItem[$p.Key] = $p.Value
    }
    $pageItem.Update()
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}


Function Get-PageLayout([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context,[string]$Name)
{
    $list = $Context.Site.GetCatalog([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListTemplateType]::MasterPageCatalog)
    $qry = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $qry.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>$Name</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
    $result = $list.GetItems($qry)
    $Context.Load($result)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    if($result.Count -gt 0) {
       return $result[0]
    }  
    return $null
 }


$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$context.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($UserName, $Password)
Add-PublishingPage -Context $context  -PageName $PageName -PageLayoutName $PageLayoutName
$context.Dispose()
```

Usage

```
./Add-PublishingPage.ps1 -Url "http://contoso.sharepoint.com/search" -UserName "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com" -Password "password" -PageName "CustomResults.aspx" -PageLayoutName "searchresults.aspx"
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a publishing page using either Out of the box or a custom page layout following is the code.

There are 2 things you need to keep in mind to follow the below function

- If you are using OOB page layout, then we are using CAML query to get page layout as an item
- If you are using a custom page layout, then we are using a path to get page layout as an item. In below example the custom page layout is assumed to be in custom folder.

---

```
#Load SharePoint Client Assemblies 
Try{
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll'
}

catch {
    Throw "Unable to load SharePoint Client runtime"
}


function Create-PublishingPage() 
{

    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$siteurl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$PageTitle,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$PageName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$PageLayoutName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][bool]$isCustomPageLayout
    )

    try
    {


        # Authenticate with site.
        #
        $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteurl) 
        $ctx.Credentials = $credentials


        if($isCustomPageLayout -eq $false)
        {
            # Get the page layout item 
            #
            $rootWeb = $ctx.Site.RootWeb
            $mpList = $rootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle('Master Page Gallery')
            $camlQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
            $camlQuery.ViewXml = '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" /><Value Type="Text">'+$PageLayoutName+'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'
            $items = $mpList.GetItems($camlQuery)
            $ctx.Load($items)
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            $pageLayoutItem = $items[0]
            $ctx.Load($pageLayoutItem)
        }
        else
        {
            # Get custom page layout and convert it to list item
            #
            $PageLayoutName = "/_catalogs/masterpage/Custom Page Layouts Folder/" + $PageLayoutName
            $items = $ctx.Site.RootWeb.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($PageLayoutName)
            $ctx.Load($items)
            $pageLayoutItem = $items.ListItemAllFields
            $ctx.Load($pageLayoutItem)
        }

        # Get publishing web object
        #
        $web = $ctx.Web
        $pubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($ctx, $web)
        $ctx.Load($pubWeb)

        # Get pages library.
        #
        $pagesList = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('Pages')


        # Create page information instance, update properties, 
        # add it, check it in, publish it, and approve it.
        # 
        $pubPageInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.PublishingPageInformation
        $pubPageInfo.Name = $PageName.Replace(" ", "-") + ".aspx"
        $pubPageInfo.PageLayoutListItem = $pageLayoutItem 
        $pubPage = $pubWeb.AddPublishingpage($pubPageInfo)

        $pubPage.ListItem.File.CheckIn("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
        $pubPage.ListItem.File.Publish("")
        $pubPage.ListItem.File.Approve("")

        $ctx.Load($pubPage) 
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        # Page added. Now retrieve list item, check it out, 
        # update title and page content, and check back in.
        #
        $listItem = $pubPage.get_listItem()
        $ctx.Load($listItem)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        $file = $listItem.File
        $file.CheckOut()
        $ctx.Load($file)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        $listItem.Set_Item("Title", $PageTitle)
        $listItem.Update()
        $listItem.File.CheckIn("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
        $listItem.File.Publish("")
        $listItem.File.Approve("")
        $ctx.Load($listItem)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        Write-Host 'New page ' $PageName ' created successfully' -ForegroundColor Cyan
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host ("Error while creating page. Error -->> " + $_.Exception.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
    }

}
```

**Usage**:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential

#Example for page with Custom Page Layout
#
Create-PublishingPage "http://somesite.com" $credentials "Some Page Title" "SomePageName" "YourCustomPageLayout.aspx" $true 

#Example for page with OOB Page Layout
#
Create-PublishingPage "http://somesite.com" $credentials "Some Page Title" "SomePageName" "ArticleLeft.aspx" $false
```